# DeserializationError: [...] Permission matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-fixtures

When running some unit tests, I get a `DeserializationError` error.  Other test classes in the same file use the same fixture correctly.  I am baffled and would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
class CreateViewTest(TransactionTestCase):

    fixtures = ['data.yaml']

    def test_create_post_passed(self):
        current = len(Timesheet.objects.all())
        data = {'start': datetime.date.today(), }
        response = self.client.post('/timetracker/create/', data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, response)
        self.assertEqual(current + 1, len(Timesheet.objects.all()))
```

And here is the output of running the unit tests:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_post_passed (timetracker.tests.CreateViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 182, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 787, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 840, in _fixture_setup
    **{'verbosity': 0, 'database': db_name})
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 90, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 141, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 79, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options):
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 132, in Deserializer
    m2m_data[field.name] = [m2m_convert(pk) for pk in field_value]
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 127, in m2m_convert
    return field.rel.to._default_manager.db_manager(db).get_by_natural_key(*value).pk
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 36, in get_by_natural_key
    content_type=ContentType.objects.db_manager(self.db).get_by_natural_key(app_label, model),
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/usr/repos/intranet/intranet_site/timetracker/fixtures/users.yaml': Permission matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Do you remember if you managed to solve this? If so, how?

Comment: @guival No fix. I refactored the code. Took ages...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem after dumping auth permissions table. After removing some permissions problem has gone. Here is the list of permissions that were removed:

```
- fields:
    codename: add_site
    content_type: [sites, site]
    name: Can add site
  model: auth.permission
- fields:
    codename: change_site
    content_type: [sites, site]
    name: Can change site
  model: auth.permission
- fields:
    codename: delete_site
    content_type: [sites, site]
    name: Can delete site
  model: auth.permission
- fields:
    codename: add_migrationhistory
    content_type: [south, migrationhistory]
    name: Can add migration history
  model: auth.permission
- fields:
    codename: change_migrationhistory
    content_type: [south, migrationhistory]
    name: Can change migration history
  model: auth.permission
- fields:
    codename: delete_migrationhistory
    content_type: [south, migrationhistory]
    name: Can delete migration history
  model: auth.permission
```

It turned out that `sites` and `south` apps were not installed in my project, so all those permissions were related to non existing apps. Those apps were installed earlier and were removed after Django upgrade. But permissions stored in database remained untouched